# change color of row selected in repeater with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a repeater with a linkbutton. So, I intend to use javascript to when click the linkbutton, in addition to be able to make data editing, can change the color of selected row.

but I do not know how to do this. Can I add an OnClientClick event? how can I know the line that you selected to be able to change the color?

Thank you...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
  <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
   </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
       <tr class="trclass" style="width:100px">
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkBtn1" OnCommand="lbEdit_Command" 
                   CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'
                    CommandName="EDIT" runat="server">
                </asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use OnClientClick event. Inside client-click "this" refers to element caused the event, so you can try something like:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkBtn1" OnCommand="lbEdit_Command" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'
    CommandName="EDIT" runat="server">
    OnClientClick = "this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'"
</asp:LinkButton>
```

this will select parent element of the clicked link which is TD and set it's background color to blue. A (probably better) alternative would be assign a CSS class instead of assigning color directly.